# Can't Launch Steam. Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, steam

My problem is that i click on the steam icon and it doesn't launch, and when i do a right-click and select something also nothing appens.

I also tried doing some "solutions" on the terminal but the terminal can't found the steam folder, I attached pictures so you can see the error, thanks.

[Translation: Directory or File Doesn't Exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL4fV.png)

Comment: Please copy and post those images from the terminal

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! In the future it makes things easier for those trying to help you if you copy and paste error text into question instead of posting a screenshot (this also makes your actual error searchable for future users) THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steam needs to be reinstalled after upgrade**

Hello fellow Steamer! I too had this same issue. You need to reinstall steam after the upgrade. Don't worry, you won't need to download your games again.

```
sudo apt purge steam
sudo apt purge steam-*
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install steam-installer steam-devices
```

Now try running steam from command line. If it still doesn't work, please post error message to your question.

Comment: thank youu, i will try, if it works i will mark it hehe

Comment: still withoout working, what can i do?

Comment: the new solutios obviously hehe

Comment: awesome! happy gaming! if you want t add me as a friend on steam, my username is "besneatte"